# Simulate Mouseclick-Events on a jailbroken device via cycript

Tags: ios, mouseevent, jailbreak, tweak

I'm interested in the iOS-Tweak "MouseSupport" [Source Code (Repo)](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-tweaks/source/browse/trunk/MouseSupport/Tweak.xm?r=114) from Matthias Ringwald. Does anybody know how to use it?

I would like to simulate Mouseclick-Events while being hooked up at SpringBoard (via cycript)
(a goal would be for example to click programmatically on buttons or just simulate a click at a specific point via coordinates).

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your goals; take a look at [cocoawithlove.com](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) or check out the [Private Framework Header](https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-) repo by masbogs on Github.